# How can I access any of the Xcode environment variables in Python?

Tags: python, xcode, bash, shell, environment-variables

Is there any way I could access any of the Xcode environment variables (BUILD_DIR, CONFIGURATION, ...) in Python?

I have tried the following command (target and configuration are input parameters):

```
os.system('xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -target ' + target + ' -configuration ' + configuration + ' -sdk iphonesimulator clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/' + configuration + '-iphonesimulator')
```

but the command failed. The ${BUILD_DIR} keyword is not returning the expected value.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using the ``env`` system call, or seeing if those variables are in [``os.environ``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)?

Comment: I get the following error message: "Key Error: BUILD_DIR" when I call os.environ['BUILD_DIR']